# Instantiating a class's subtype in the companion object's apply method in Scala

Tags: scala, apply, factory-pattern, subtype, companion-object

I've been knocking myself out trying to use a companion object to instantiate one of a class's subtypes. It's not known at compile time which subclass will be instantiated. This is remarkably similar to an example found in *Programming Scala* starting on page 127. I've contrived an example here:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._


abstract class Animal
class Dog extends Animal { def bark = "woof" }
class Cat extends Animal { def meow = "meow" }

object Animal {
  def apply(specify: String): Option[Animal] = {
    specify match {
      case "dog" => Some(new Dog)
      case "cat" => Some(new Cat)
      case _     => None
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  def getType[T: TypeTag](obj: T) = typeOf[T]

  var dog = Animal("dog")
  println(getType(dog))
}
```

This program prints out `scala.Option[Animal]`. I'd expect it to print out `scala.Option[Dog]`. Furthermore, if I attempt to add the line `println(dog.bark)` to the end of the `Test` object, it fails to compile. Is this simply impossible?

I've been poring over Scala reflection documentation, but it seems very dense and difficult. Furthermore, this seems to be exactly how the *Programming Scala* example works, so I can't imagine what I've done wrong here.

---

EDIT: This version doesn't have reflection and simply throws a compile-time error due to the wrong type.

```
abstract class Animal
class Dog extends Animal { def bark = "woof" }
class Cat extends Animal { def meow = "meow" }

object Animal {
  def apply(specify: String): Option[Animal] = {
    specify match {
      case "dog" => Some(new Dog)
      case "cat" => Some(new Cat)
      case _     => None
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  var dog = Animal("dog")
  println(dog.get.bark)
}

// $ scalac test.scala
// test.scala:17: error: value bark is not a member of Animal
//   println(dog.get.bark)
//                   ^
// one error found
```

---

EDIT: Evidently this requires pattern matching to work out. Here is a working example, somewhat simplified.

```
abstract class Animal
class Dog extends Animal { def bark = "woof" }
class Cat extends Animal { def meow = "meow" }

object Animal {
  def apply(specify: String): Animal = {
    specify match {
      case "dog" => new Dog
      case "cat" => new Cat
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val dog = Animal("dog")
  dog match {
    case d: Dog => println(d.bark)
    case _      =>
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives compile error: ` error: No TypeTag available for Option[this.Animal]`. Which version of Scala are you using?

Comment: I have 2.11.4 installed. I'll amend to add a version that doesn't use reflection (and simply fails to compile due to the type problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible.

In the second example, `Animal.apply` always returns `Option[Animal]`, because that is its type signature.

Your `object Test` is really saying, expanded out a bit:

```
object Test extends App {
  var dog: Option[Animal] = Animal.apply("dog")
  println(dog.get.bark)
}
```

The compiler *might* be able to tell at compile time that it could be an `Option[Dog]`, but the language's semantics don't allow for that: the grammar would have to be much more complex to be able to encapsulate that knowledge.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying, it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, it is impossible as-is.

Comment: You could do a `match` or `isInstanceOf` to check its type at runtime... but that's not what you want, I think.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing what's fundamentally different between this and the example from *Programming Scala*.

Comment: In the examples around p. 127, the book doesn't call methods that are only in the subclasses without first using `match` to check the type (as in the spec example on p. 128).

Comment: Somehow, I was sure I'd tried that. I'll edit to add a working version.

Comment: "It is impossible."  "It sounds like you're saying, it's not possible."  It's like an xkcd strip! +1 to you both.